# Momentum and conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision, projectile

In this problem, I am confused about whether to use energy conservation or momentum conservation? I found this in a book by Resnick and tried every possible method I could think of but could not reach a conclusion. I am preparing for my mock exams and really need help with this problem. Thank you

Q ) A wood block of mass mw = 200 g is projected from the ground at a speed v0 = 35 m/s and
at an angle θ0 = 50º. When at height h = 24 m the wood block was hit by a bullet of mass mb =
25 g which was moving at vb = 220 m/s and at an angle θb = 70º. After the collision, the bullet
embedded itself in the block and move together and land at point A on the ground. Then they
move on the ground that has coefficient of kinetic friction µk = 0.5 and start to compress a
horizontal spring at point B. The distance between point A and B is 18 m and the spring
constant k = 3×102 N/m. Right end of the spring is fixed, and all motions are confined in x-y
plane.
a) Was the collision between the wood block and the bullet elastic or inelastic?
Explain quantitively.
b) How far is point A from the launch point of the wood block?
c) Calculate the velocity at which the block-bullet system lands at point A. What will be the
speed of it at point B?
d) Determine how much the spring will be compressed when the block-bullet system comes
to a rest.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We do not offer complete solutions on this site, but we can hint at an approach.

For the collision, you must use conservation of momentum (specifically, conservation of momentum in 2 dimensions).

Although gravity acts on both objects throughout the collision, the work done by gravity will be insignificant (since the collision takes a very short amount of time). From there, use conservation of energy.

Comment: I think I have found a result for part b and c. Are they 69.56m and 254.5m by any chance. I just need to know if I am on the right track.